# youtube playlist plays next video in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, playlist

im using this youtube playlist plugin http://geckohub.com/jquery/youtubeplaylist/ and im trying to find a way of adding a bit of code that will allow the list of videos to be played next after the main video has finished playing. I have managed to loop the main video but trying to get the next video on the list to play.

cheers
Steve

Comment: Try with this URL http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2009/10/youtube-javascript-player-with-playlist.html

Answer (score 0):

check this URl [autoplay youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097686/autoplay-youtube-video) it is not using this youtubeplaylist plugin. But you will get some idea to call next video when **statechange**

```
var o = document.getElementById( 'ytplayer_object' );
    if ( o )
    {
      o.addEventListener( "onStateChange", "ytplayer_statechange" );
      o.addEventListener( "onError", "ytplayer_error" );
    }
```